# Notify when master function called at same time by two or more function calls

Tags: python, development-environment

I have one normal function(master function) in python when master function called at same time from two or more function calls,
then function need to display message like "two or more functions called at a time".

```
def master_func(x):
    print(x)
```

master_func(x1) and master_func(x2) at same time, I need notification like "two or more functions
called at a time"

I did lot of research but unable to find any reference for my use case, please give some idea so that I can work on it.

Comment: Not sure what the surrounding context is, but you could try using a variable in the broader scope that functions as some kind of counter. Increment it at the start of main_func, check its value to see how many calls are "active", then decrement before any function return. Definitely brittle though, and would be susceptible to failure  from errors. Maybe you can build on that?

Comment: python functions won't run at the same time unless u are using some multiprocessing module, so the answer is 0.